# ASP.NET Webservice fails

Tags: mysql, asp.net, web-services

I have an excel sheet connected to a MySQL database, which uses an asp.net  webservice to talk to each other.

It all runs pretty well, however sometimes the web service fails.

For example I run an UPDATE query via the webservice, and data doesn't get updated.

However I run exactly the same UPDATE query a few minutes later and is updated correctly.

So there is no error on the SQL query,seems more like a webservice fail issue at certain times.

There are many people using the same webservice, so I am wondering if several people happen to access the same webservice exactly at the same time is causing the issue.

Could that be the reason? If so, how can I prevent it from happening ?

Is there a way I can check if the webservice query has failed ? (without comparing the data that is actually in the database, as this would take too long)

thanks

Comment: Does the web service write logs? If yes, what do they say about the failed attempts? If not... why not?

Comment: to be honest, no, the webservice doesn't write logs...Reason because I was too busy creating the system and didn't think of it.  Any advice how to write logs would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked your Windows event application log?

Comment: yes, i get the same long events in both Mysql Server Logs and Windows Events...IP address '10.xxx.xx.xxx' could not be resolved: not such host is known.
But doesn't tell me much, what the issue is.

Comment: "no such host is known. But doesn't tell me much, what the issue is"...it's telling you that the host (i.e. computer) at that IP address does not exist (or at least, is not running). So check the IP address is correct, there's no firewall in between, network is reliable, the remote service is running correctly, not overloaded etc.